# AS3: Access my Main.as from a movieclip on stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, menu, navigation, movieclip

*Using Adobe Flash Professional CS6, AS3*
Please let me know if I need to provide any more info
I am trying to set up a navigation menu and my question is, "How do I get a MovieClip to call a function in my Main.as file from the Stage?"  There is only one frame (I do not want more) and the different menu screens, which are just MovieClips, are added to the stage with AS when needed.  I have a public function in the file Main.as called **_About()**, that my MovieClip, "MenuScreen", cannot access.  I can successfully have _Menu() add a MovieClip to the stage with eventListeners, but when the mc makes the call back to change screens I get this error:

*TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Stage@51ca0d1 to flash.display.MovieClip. at MenuScreen/clickAbout()[MenuScreen::frame1:32]*

Frame1:32's code is:

```
MovieClip(parent)._About();
```

Line 51 in my Main.as is:

```
public function _About():void
{
trace("The About Function");
}
```

Below I have detailed more about **Main.as** with most of the fat trimmed.

```
package 
{
import stuff

public class Main extends MovieClip
{
    //Load the screen MCs onto the stage
    public var _menu:MenuScreen = new MenuScreen();
    public var _about:AboutScreen = new AboutScreen();
    public var isMenu:Boolean = true;
    public var isAbout:Boolean = false;

    public function Main()
    {
        _Menu();            
    }

    public function _Menu():void
    {
        isMenu = true;
        stage.addChild(_menu);
    }

    public function _About():void
    {
        trace("The About Function");
    }
```

Comment: Your naming conventions are your own however I need to ask why you have used `_Caps` for a public method when typically `_` is used for private members and all members are `pascalCase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set static property :

```
public static var instance:Main;
public function Main(){
        instance = this;
        _Menu();            
    }
```

and then from anywhere You can use code :

```
Main.instance._About();
```

Comment: While this is definitely doable, it would not be a good design pattern to follow. Depending on the size / complexity of your application, you should strive to avoid using public static variables that any other object in your system can access. This is basically an example of a rather careless Singleton. It will lead to spaghetti code that is difficult to debug. A potentially more robust solution would be to use a command pattern or utility classes that provide more generic functionality.

Comment: Yeah , and how many Main instance items You will have ? Always 1 . difficult to debug ? I have no idea why ... It is not a good designe pattern , i know , but best solution in small application like this made on flash timeline .

Comment: When something is available on the global scope it can be called, accessed and possibly modified anywhere else in the program. This can  cause problems as an applications grows. @Larusso has the right idea with using events to transmit messages that trigger functionality.

Comment: @turbosqel - Thank you so much!  While this method doesn't seem to be the most popular around here, it did _exactly_ what I needed and makes perfect sense to me.  I know it's supposed to be bad practice for something to be globally accessible all the time, but it is just what I want from my Main class.  I'm still new to this yet, so I will probably see the error of my ways one day...

Comment: Dont forget its good for small apps . When You make bigger stuff , use events .

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to your problem would be to add the menu items not to the stage! Instead add them to your main class. This way the parent of your items is instead main.as

But then you need to cast the parent to Main

```
Main(parent)._About();
```

Also not very nice. The items should not now what is behind them.

The best way is to do it, is to dispatch events from the different screens.
Means: you create your screen objects an there are dispatching custom events when a screnn change should happen.

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("showAbout"));
```

in your main class you handle the events like:

```
public function Main()
{
    _Menu(); 
    _menu = new MenuScreen();
    _menu.addEventHandler("showAbout", showAboutHandler);
}

public function showAboutHanlder(e:Event):void
{
     _About();
}
```

Even more better is a custom event with a screen identifier as a param. This way you just add one handler and decide in the handler code which screen to be displayed.

With the event handling in place, your menu items have no direct connection to the main. Also the main needs no further information about the screen classes.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see `MenuScreen`'s complete class, but here's what's probably going on:

You're instantiating at `public var _menu:MenuScreen = new MenuScreen();` and when this happens it's probably making the call to `MovieClip(parent)._About()` before you've added `MenuScreen` to the stage at `stage.addChild(_menu);` - It doesn't have a parent yet when this occurs and the error incurs.

Two ways to get around this:

- Add a required parameter in `MenuScreen`'s constructor that references your `Main` class. Your constructor in `MenuScreen` would start with `public function MenuScreen($main:Main){` and when you instantiate `MenuScreen` from `Main` class you would write `public var _menu:MenuScreen = new MenuScreen(this);` now you can use $main._About() in `MenuScreen`'s constuctor.
- In `MenuScreen`'s constructor add a listener that checks when it's been added to the stage:  `addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedStage)`. In the function `addedStage` you can properly call for a parent or the stage, and `MovieClip(parent)._About()` will probably work here.